# How to zoom out decision tree plot in r studio?

Tags: r, decision-tree

I have plotted a decision tree using `ctree()` present in the party package. The decision tree is in the screenshot. The nodes of the tree are overlapping so I am not able to see them. I tried the zoom option present their, but it is just zoom in. Can you please suggest me how to zoom out so I can see all the nodes clearly?

[image: 1]]

Comment: Welcome to stackOverflow. Please see the following link for [how to as a great question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and this link for [how to create a minimum example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We need additional information to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not entirely clear and you havent specified what you have tried.
But as far as I understand, you can try the following method.

You can specify the width and height to get a better view.

`{r, fig.width = 100, fig.height=45 }
plot(your_ctree_here)`